# Excel: Check to see if Two Values are Between Two Other Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a nightmare of a time trying to find a solution to this problem, and am hoping you wizards can help.

In the example below, I have a dataset (columns A through C), and reference columns (F to H). Column D is the desired output for the formula. This column has been populated with an example of the output I want.

**Table 1.**

[image: Dataset 1]

Table 1 shows my dataset. My goal is to generate (using a formula) an output in `column D` that classifies whether data in `rows 2-14` in `columns B & C` fall within the start and end parameters of my reference dataset in `columns G & H`. If true, the formula should return the line number as shown in `column F` where the match exists in `column D`.

Using `IF(AND(` formulas, I was able to figure out how to do this so long as the start and end of B & C were `>= to G`, and `<= to H`, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it if the start and end of Line 3 is partially outside of Line 1. Example: `=IF(AND(B2>=$G$2,C2<=$H$2),$F$2,IF(AND(B2>=$G$3,C2<=$H$3),$F$3,"<null>"))`

As depicted in `Figure 1` below, Line 1 shows the bounds that are described in 'G2:H2', while Line 2 shows the bounds described in 'G3:H3'. My goal is to see if Lines 3 & 4 overlap with Line 1 or Line 2, and output a variable like shown in 'column D'. Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you.

**Figure 1.**

[image: Figure 1]

I do not want to be defeated by one lousy dataset.

Comment: What you mean by overlap.  Any overlap? Overlap entirely?

Comment: Instead of AND, you must use OR for partial overlap.

AND is for entire overlap !

Comment: Any overlap, sorry I should have specified.. If I change that formula I listed above to OR, they all result in Line 1 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another,

```
=IF(NOT(OR(OR(AND(B2>=S$2,B2<=T$2),AND(C2>=S$2,C2<=T$2)), OR(AND(B2>=S$3,B2<=T$3),AND(C2>=S$3,C2<=T$3)))), "<null>", 
    SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(OR(AND(B2>=S$2, B2<=T$2), AND(C2>=S$2, C2<=T$2)), 1, TEXT(,))&CHAR(32)&
                    IF(OR(AND(B2>=S$3, B2<=T$3), AND(C2>=S$3, C2<=T$3)), 2, TEXT(,))), CHAR(32), " & "))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you sir. I will mark this as correct as you were the first to reply. I am truly greatful for your help! TIme to reverse engineer and learn from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Fully functional, albeit a little lengthy.

```
=IF(IF(OR(AND(B2>=$G$2,B2<=$H$2),AND(C2>=$G$2,C2<=$H$2)),$F$2,"")&IF(OR(AND(B2>=$G$3,B2<=$H$3),AND(C2>=$G$3,C2<=$H$3)),$F$3,"")<>"",IF(OR(AND(B2>=$G$2,B2<=$H$2),AND(C2>=$G$2,C2<=$H$2)),$F$2&IF(OR(AND(B2>=$G$3,B2<=$H$3),AND(C2>=$G$3,C2<=$H$3))=TRUE," & ",""),"")&IF(OR(AND(B2>=$G$3,B2<=$H$3),AND(C2>=$G$3,C2<=$H$3)),$F$3,""),"<Null>")
```

Comment: your formula also works fantastic. I have marked Jeeped's answer as correct as he beat you by 1 minute :( Thank you so much for your help. I have upvoted to show my gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

The omission was in not checking for the possibility that the line in question (B&C)
spanned both of the other line segments. In addition, this check needs to be done first:

```
IF(AND(B12>=L1Start,B12<=L1End,C12>=L2Start,C12<=L2End),"1 & 2",IF(AND(B12>=L1Start,B12<=L1End),1,IF(AND(B12>=L2Start,B12<=L2End),2,"<null>")))
```

For readability, I named the start & stop cells, L1Start & L1End, L2Start & L2Endals, unless the line numbers in Col F change, I hardend them as well, but easy enough to change those to the respective cell references if needed --  otherwise the original statement is pretty much as provided.

Here are my results:

[image]

Hope that helps...

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Cell D2: `=IF(AND(OR(AND((B2<$G$2);(C2>$G$2));AND((B2>$G$2);(B2<$H$2)));OR(AND((B2<$G$3);(C2>$G$3));AND((B2>$G$3);(C2<$H$3))));"1 & 2";IF(OR(AND((B2<$G$2);(C2>$G$2));AND((B2>$G$2);(B2<$H$2)));"1";IF(OR(AND((B2<$G$3);(C2>$G$3));AND((B2>$G$3);(C2<$H$3)));"2";"<null>")))` in Mac

Cell D2: `=IF(AND(OR(AND((B2<$G$2),(C2>$G$2)),AND((B2>$G$2),(B2<$H$2))),OR(AND((B2<$G$3),(C2>$G$3)),AND((B2>$G$3),(C2<$H$3)))),"1 & 2",IF(OR(AND((B2<$G$2),(C2>$G$2)),AND((B2>$G$2),(B2<$H$2))),"1",IF(OR(AND((B2<$G$3),(C2>$G$3)),AND((B2>$G$3),(C2<$H$3))),"2","<null>")))` in Windows

Obviously, you will have to copy until D14 and only row of B and C cells should change.

Comment: The OP's sample used commas as a regional list separator.

Comment: Unfortunately Fred I was unable to get your code to work. Thank you for your help nonetheless!

Comment: Gosh.. couldn't you just change ";" for "," ?

Answer (score 1):

Think that this will scale better if you were to add more lines

[image]